# React-Redux connected component failing to update view/trigger rerender when setState is called

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, redux, react-redux, callback

Im using a redux connected component in react. Just having trouble rendering a button after the handleSubmit onClick handler is called. It only appears after I refresh the page, which may indicate an async issue. So in this component, I have a redux state property called status and have mapped it to the props of my local state. I have heard that when the state or props change, that is when the component rerenders. So what I thought about doing is in my render method, if this.state.showButton is true, then this button would show. However it doesnt. I also console logged this.state.showButton and it is indeed true.

[image]

But button is not there. I did the following:

```
class VerificationForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      formError: false,
      showModal: false,
      showButton: false
    };
  }


   handleSubmit = (e) => {

     e.preventDefault();

     this.setState({
       formError: showFormError
     });

 verifyLevelOne()
       .then((data) => {
         const { status } = this.props;
         const verified = status === 'VERIFIED';
         this.setState({
           showButton: verified
         }, () => {
           actions.showSubmissionNotification(data);
         });
         console.log('Hereeeeee', this.state.showButton);
       });
   }



  render() {
    const {
      classes, actions, status
    } = this.props;
    const {
       formError, showModal
    } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} autoComplete="off">
          <Grid className={classes.container} container direction="column" alignItems="center" xs={12}>
            <Grid container direction="column" xs={11}>
              
              <span style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-around' }}>
                <Button fullWidth onClick={this.handleSubmit} type="submit" variant="contained" color="primary">Submit Information</Button>
                { this.state.showButton && <Button onClick={this.handleShowModal}  variant="contained" color="primary">Proceed</Button> }
              </span>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    status: state.global.verification.status,
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: {
      ...bindActionCreators({
        showNotification,
        showSubmissionNotification,


      }, dispatch)
    }
  };
}

const base = withRouter((withStyles(styles)(VerificationForm)));
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(base);
```

Answer (score 0):

setState is executed asynchronous, so if you `console.log` just after the setstate it will **not** give you the right value

I would suggest to `console.log` in return of render just when you are using the state for sack of debugging.
refer below:

```
<span style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-around' }}>
            <Button fullWidth onClick={this.handleSubmit} type="submit" variant="contained" color="primary">Submit Information</Button>
            { console.log(this.state.showButton)}
            { this.state.showButton && <Button onClick={this.handleShowModal}  variant="contained" color="primary">Proceed</Button> }
          </span>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for that advice. So I did that and can see that initially, it is false. Then after I click submit, it becomes true. However, the button is not there still

Comment: Can you share where all you are setting value for showButton.